# Rasa Agent does not support more than 23 req/sec

Tags: rasa

As we were doing a stress testing of a Rasa Agen before deploying on the production, we encountered that it only supports 23 requests per second with a response time of 1 second.

If we try to increase the requests by more than 23, then the response time increases gradually; it becomes more than 5 seconds, regardless of its hardware.

Is there any way to eliminate this limit?

I am on Rasa version 2.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have done a similar kind of [exercise](https://github.com/digiteinfotech/kairon/tree/master/stress_test) for [kAIron](https://kairon.digite.com/), which internally uses rasa 2.1.2 and not able to have more than 23 req/seq; even with our chat server implementation using tornado, which still under development, we can reach 32 req/seq max with response time up to 1 sec.

In our experience, to achieve more concurrency, one option is to deploy the rasa chat server on [Kubernetes](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/how-to-deploy/) with [horizontal scaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)